# Populate SELECT with data from JSON file using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am new with using JSON file for web development and I got interest with it due to it usefulness and power in terms of data storage. Right now, I want to use JSON file via path instead of adding the JSON into the same page because it make the page full of `JSON` data. Yesterday I have the following codes but only adding the JSON file into the same page not into separate one. How can I use JSON file path instead of adding JSON into the same page?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplier_bank_name">Bank Name</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="supplier_bank_name" name="supplier_bank_name"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PREVIOUS CODE**
This code will work well but JSON only in the same page.

```
var allbanks = {
        banks:[
            {
                "index": 0,
                "bankname": "1st Source Bank",
                "location": "USA",
                "website": "www.1stsource.com"
            },
            {
                "index": 1,
                "bankname": "1st Summit Bank",
                "location": "North America",
                "website": "www.1stsummit.com"
            },
            {
                "index": 2,
                "bankname": "A.J. Smith Federal Savings Bank",
                "location": "USA",
                "website": "www.ajsmithbank.com"
            }
        ]
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Bank</option>';

        for (var i = 0; i < allbanks.banks.length; i++) {
            listItems += "<option data-tokens='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "' value='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "'>" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "</option>";
        }

        $("#supplier_bank_name").html(listItems);
    });
```

**SCRIPT TODAY**
Not working and looking for solution

```
var allbanks = (function () {
    var allbanks = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'js/allbanks.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            allbanks = data;
        }
    });
    return allbanks;
})(); 


$(document).ready(function () {
    var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Bank</option>';

    for (var i = 0; i < allbanks.banks.length; i++) {
        listItems += "<option data-tokens='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "' value='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "'>" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "</option>";
     }

    $("#supplier_bank_name").html(listItems);
});
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "banks": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "bankname": "1st Source Bank",
            "location": "USA",
            "website": "www.1stsource.com"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "bankname": "1st Summit Bank",
            "location": "North America",
            "website": "www.1stsummit.com"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "bankname": "A.J. Smith Federal Savings Bank",
            "location": "USA",
            "website": "www.ajsmithbank.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there an error? Because your code should work (and it does): https://plnkr.co/edit/ArfHEmkeNtIJUoQUGK6H?p=preview

Comment: The following code are valuable and solve my problem thinking about connect JSON with html. But when make a collaboration of your code to my codes it didn't work. I think their are some conflict between my our codes. I created a repository at Github of my whole file in order for me to get help from you sir @dork. the file are located here https://github.com/Ailyn09/project102 I hope you've got an interest to commit with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.ajax` is an asynchronous function, the code within `allbanks` will execute in this order:

1. Assign `allbanks` to `null`
2. Make `ajax` request
3. Return `allbanks`, which is still set to `null` because the ajax request has not returned yet.
4. Receive data and assign that to `allbanks` (This will not return out of the function and will not be set to the `allbanks` variable on the first line)

To fix this, you should use the data within the `success` portion of the ajax request.

```
function createSelectItems(data) {
    var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Bank</option>';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.banks.length; i++) {
        listItems += "<option data-tokens='" + data.banks[i].bankname + "' value='" + data.banks[i].bankname + "'>" + data.banks[i].bankname + "</option>";
    }

    $("#supplier_bank_name").html(listItems);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'js/allbanks.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            createSelectItems(data);
        }
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

See comments below:

**allbank_connect.js**

```
// Code goes here
var allbanks = (function () {
  var allbanks = null;

  $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'js/allbanks.json',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        allbanks = data;
    }
  });

  return allbanks;
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
  var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Bank</option>';

  for (var i = 0; i < allbanks.banks.length; i++) {
    listItems += "<option data-tokens='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "' value='" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "'>" + allbanks.banks[i].bankname + "</option>";
  }

  $("#supplier_bank_name").html(listItems);
});
```

Comment: *"Since $.ajax is an asynchronous function"* - OP's code says `'async': false`. So does yours.

Comment: It didn't  work. Where do I add  `createSelectItems` function?

Comment: nnnnn is right, I missed that  you had `'async': false` in there.  Are you able to verify the data is being received by adding console.log(data) to the success function.   I believe your original code should work.

Comment: The codes are not working maybe it because of having conflict between our codes or I missed somthing with my codes. Please collaborate with me and commit with my codes at Github that located at https://github.com/Ailyn09/project102. i hope that you will able to commit with it in order to help me with my problem. @Jason Lemrond

Comment: I cloned your repository but in order for me to push back it requires me to have permission.  (https://github.com/jlemrond is my github account).  However, I put the edited portion of the code in the answer above.  The only thing I changed to get the ajax request working was change the url on the request from `allbanks.json` to `js/allbanks.json`.  Ajax requests will be relative to the html file that calls them, not the js file it's in.  However, in the example you provided in your question, the url was correct.  Let me know if this still isn't working on your end.